# Trying to send authenticated email using Net::SMTP::SSL

Tags: perl, email, authentication, ssl, smtp

I'm attempting to send an authenticated email with the Net::SMTP::SSL module to a comcast email server. I'm using the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::SMTP::SSL;
use MIME::Base64;

$smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new
    (
    "smtp.comcast.net",
    Hello => "host.comcast.net",
    Port => 465,
    Timeout => 30,
    Debug => 1,
    );
$smtp->datasend("AUTH LOGIN\n");
$smtp->response();

# Mailbox info
$smtp->datasend(encode_base64('username')); # username
$smtp->response();
$smtp->datasend(encode_base64('password')); # password
$smtp->response();

# Email from
$smtp->mail('user\@comcast.net');

# Email to
$smtp->to('user\@host.com');

$smtp->data();

$smtp->datasend("To: user\@host.com\n");
$smtp->datasend("From: user\@comcast.net\n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: Test");

# Line break to separate headers from body
$smtp->datasend("\n");

$smtp->datasend("Blah\n");
$smtp->dataend();

$smtp->quit();
exit;
```

I'm basically following the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583987/how-to-use-perl-for-smtp-connection-with-user-and-ssl-auth-and-send-emails-with) for comcast.

I've ran telnet and can connect to the smtp server on the port and I can issue the AUTH LOGIN and successfully login, but issuing the

```
$smtp->datasend("AUTH LOGIN\n");
```

always results in:

```
Can't call method "datasend" on an undefined value
```

I've also tried executing the auth method to login and that fails as well.

What am I missing here?  I know it's something simple I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all of the [`Net::SMTP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSMTP) methods optionally set error codes, so I suspect that [`Net::SMTP::SSL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSMTP%3a%3aSSL) does the same.  Try the following for your constructor:

```
use Net::SMTP::SSL;
use MIME::Base64;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new(
    "smtp.comcast.net",
    Hello => "host.comcast.net",
    Port => 465,
    Timeout => 30,
    Debug => 1,
) or die "Failed to connect to mail server: $!";
```

<strike>Also, the fact that your smtp server is different than your Hello is a little suspect to me.</strike>

Comment: Hello is used to identify your sever.  From the Net::SMTP perldoc: Hello - SMTP requires that you identify yourself. This option specifies a string to pass as your mail domain. If not given localhost.localdomain will be used.

Comment: You're right.  I'm so used to writing code that is local to the smtp server.  Forgot that.  Regardless, the error code should probably tell you what's wrong with your constructor.

Comment: So the issue appears to be with my resolver.  I substituted an IP address for the smtp server in the constructor and this corrected the issue. I'm looking at my network setup now to see where the issue resides.  Thanks for responding though.

Answer (score 0):

For email services that use STARTTLS, it's best to use the newer NET::SMTPS module. Try the following code:

```
my $msg = MIME::Lite ->new (  
From => 'from@bellsouth.net',
To => 'to@bellsouth.net',
Subject => 'Test Message',
Data => 'This is a test',
Type => 'text/html'
);

my $USERNAME = 'from@bellsouth.net';
my $PASSWORD = 'abc123'; 

my $smtps = Net::SMTPS->new("smtp.mail.att.net", Port => 587,  doSSL => 'starttls', SSL_version=>'TLSv1');

$smtps->auth ( $USERNAME, $PASSWORD ) or die("Could not authenticate with bellsouth.\n");

$smtps ->mail('from@bellsouth.net');
$smtps->to('to@bellsouth.net');
$smtps->data();
$smtps->datasend( $msg->as_string() );  
$smtps->dataend();  
$smtps->quit;
```

Originally from http://www.skipser.com/p/2/p/send-email-using-perl-via-live.com.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

#### Email from

***Change***

`$smtp->mail('user\@comcast.net');` to  `$smtp->mail('user@comcast.net');` without `'\'`

#### Email to

***Change***

`$smtp->to('user\@host.com');` to `$smtp->to('user@host.com');` without `'\'`